# Dynamically add "selected" to HTML option via DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Right now I'm trying to use JavaScript to dynamically add some `<select>` elements to an HTML page; specifically, `<select>` elements that will let people choose the time. I'm most of the way there:

```
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

  var hrSelect = document.createElement("select");
  hrSelect.name = "div_hr";

  for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    var hrOption = document.createElement("option");
    var hrStr = String(i);
    if (i < 10) {
      hrStr = "0" + hrStr;
    }
    hrOption.value = hrStr;
    hrOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hrStr));
    hrSelect.appendChild(hrOption);
  }

  newDiv.appendChild(hrSelect);
```

This by itself works fine. So here's the thing: I want to make one of these options `selected` and appear by default, and I don't know how to do that. Something like:

```
    if (i == 12) {
      hrOption.selected = true;
    }
```

But this doesn't work for me. I can't find out how to make this work; a Google search doesn't give any helpful options. Can anyone guide me toward the answer?

(For those of you curious, I want to make the `selected` options default to the current time. I already know how to get the time via PHP and `echo` it into my JavaScript.)

EDIT: as it turns out, my intended solution was correct. I'm not sure why it didn't work for me when I tested it. Voting to close.

Comment: That is, in fact, how you do it: set the "selected" property to `true`.

Comment: You can also set `hrSelect.selectedIndex` to the index of the option you want to be selected.

Comment: @Pointy I swear it did not work when I tried it the first time. For some reason it works now, so I guess that takes care of that :| thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `selectedIndex` property:

```
hrSelect.selectedIndex = 12;
```

Comment: This will work, but [so will the code in the OP](http://jsfiddle.net/dc6q82vm/).

Comment: True. But this is one statement, that's something that has to be executed each time through the loop. So this seems a little better.